# Postgresql trigger for when timestamp is reached

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm building a table that stores user subscription details in Postgresql. Is there some sort of trigger function or event for when certain timestamp is reached?
Example: User: A, Subscribed at: 17:00:00 11/01/2019, Expires in: 1 month
Do postgresql supports something like setTimeout(1 month) or setInterval(1 month)?

I've read the [postgres documentation on trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/trigger-definition.html) which says that functions can be triggered only on operation (crud).

Comment: No, there’s nothing like that built in. You’ll have to handle those things separately. pgAgent may be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) which can handle this kind of tasks.