# how to add row based on expiry date on others row?

Tags: postgresql, architecture, scheduled-tasks, background-process

so I have a table `A` which has a column `expiry date`. When this date is passed I have to call a API and add new data to table. What is way to do this
things i have thought of are

1. Database trigger: The problem is trigger can be set only on update, insert.
2. Creating a separate service which checks expiry, call api and add new data, this problem is expiry_date is just for some seconds, so if this api is slow i will not be able to show latest data.
   The main problem i feel with both of solutions is db will receive lots of queries, so i wanted to know if there is other way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql trigger for when timestamp is reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56088688/postgresql-trigger-for-when-timestamp-is-reached)

Comment: No, the extension mentioned in that answer is just a cron_job scheduler inside db, Also triggers wont work because i need to call a rest api to get data.

Comment: True, I suggested that thread just to clarify the first option in your question - there's no time-based trigger mechanism in PostgreSQL, making `pg_cron` the closest best for in-db solutions. For security reasons, postgres can't call external programs, so even if there were time-based triggers, you still couldn't call the API.

Comment: The external service doesn't need to constantly poll the expiry dates, if that's what you were afraid would slow everything down and overload the system with queries. A service can [`listen`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-listen.html) on a channel for a [`notify`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-notify.html) from a `trigger on insert`, and when it gets one, set up a regular `cron` job based on the expiry date. When the expiry date is reached, `cron` can send a `notify` to your other, API-calling service, that's listening for it.

Comment: I have thought of this @Zegarek , the problem is that data is loaded only for one, and based on expiry of that I have insert new. As of now i could only think pf one way which is constantly poll for `expiry_dates`

Comment: I don't think I understand. Once an action is taken for an expired row and the API-caller inserts a new one, a `trigger on insert` sends a `notify` to set up a cron job for that new one. I don't see what polling solves or improves here. Can you add an example, where that would be the case, or expand the question to clarify that part a bit?